# Find element with xpath in c# selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have this element in my source code, I get h2 element with inner text(yahoo), and I want to access the nearest article that contains h2.

```
<article>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <header>
   <a></a>
   <a>
     <h2>yahoo</h2>
  </a>
 </header>
</article>
```

my written XPath is this : `//h2[text()='yahoo']//..//..`
but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you please share you c# code? I want to know how you are using this?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are expecting when you say access to nearest article, that contain h2 ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this xpath:

```
//h2[. = 'yahoo']/ancestor::article[1]
```

Comment: i have 2 article with this features,first article h2 text is google and second article h2 text is yahoo,this just working when yahoo is in the first article.

Comment: @user3796324 I don't quite understand. Could you please edit your post and show us what you really want.

Comment: This would be the right way of constructing this XPath selector.   Now, if only the OP could shed some light on what they really want, as it seems this answer was not sufficient.  (According to the question as it is written, this answers it perfectly)

Answer (score 0):

One possible XPath to get `<article>` elements containing `<h2>` element equals `yahoo` :

```
//article[.//h2='yahoo']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're want to interract with article, use next string:

```
//article[header//h2[text='yahoo']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this xpath and try : `//h2[text()='yahoo']//..//..//..`

Explanation:

1st `//..` is taking you to the anchor(a) tag.

2nd `//..` is taking you to header tag.

**3rd `//..` will take you where you want to be i.e article tag.**

Comment: Are you sure about this? I think this xpath will select more than just the `article` element.

Comment: S. It will select article element. Was the user's task to select the first `article` tag  that has `h2` tag?

Comment: In my opinion, it will select `h2`, it's parent `a`, it's parent `header`, and it's parent `article`.